# How do you Specify a target directory for a txt file to be passed in

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

`enter code here`I am trying to specify a directory for a txt.file which is being created when the jar file is run, is there anyway to specify as an argument in the console the directory of where i want that txt file to be created:

Below is the main arguments:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub C:\Users\802591720\Documents\mystuff\Programs\JavaCode\xmlSchema\ManageBillingCreditAndDebit.20130219.xsd
    //String fileName = "ManageBillingCreditAndDebit.20130219.xsd";
    //String Source = "C:\Users\607817544\as1\";
    String path1 = args[0];
    String FileName = args[1];
    TagDef tagDef;
String[] operations;
try {
    operations = listOperationsUnique("C:\\Users\\607817544\\as1\\ManageBillingCreditAndDebit.20130219.wsdl");
    System.out.println("operation:" + operations.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < operations.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("operation:" + operations[i]);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    tagDef = refheader(path1, FileName); 

    System.out.println("=================================================================");
    System.out.println("Tag details");
    System.out.println(tagDef);
    System.out.println("=================================================================");

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

}
}

And this is the writing of the file:

```
System.out.println("");
                 fh.openFile("hello.txt");
                 fh.writeLine("");
                 fh.closeFile();
```

How do i go about specifying where I want to that file to be created in the command console? Last piece for my Java Application so any pointer would be great guys!

Any help guys is amazing, its such a minor issue I cant seem to get around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Swing text field to open up when you click on jar, and after entering the path in the text field, give submit action which should take the data from text field and do your further logic.

so giving UI like this to enter path is actually good way..

Comment: I wont be clicking on the Jar at all, I will be specifying the location of a WDSL i want parsed via the main arguments args[0] etc. If am already creating a file is there a way I can add an argument to specify where I want the txt file to be created. There is no UI involved, only the command prompt

Comment: oh okie..sorry for wrong understanding...if that is the case you just add one more argument on command line console and read args[index] assign it to path like String path = args[index] ...this should give you the path at run time what u specify in console while running the program...

Comment: See I know that much but the write file is located elsewhere, how Am i suppose to specify for that argument that its to write the file to the inserted location if that makes sense, I could add a third argument but it does nothing so am not sure what the next. step is as minor as it seems, I have a path and file name arguments within my main to specfiy the location of a WDSL, the file is also written when the Jar file runs its just a matter of giving it a target directory, where am stuck on currently